# Quick explanation of state management with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I just started using react hooks and I have a quick question. Can I just declare
`const [page] = useState(1);`
instead of `const [page, setPage] = useState(1);`
and not call setPage at all? the reason I ask is because I see that by using setPage I cause an unnecessary render of the page with the current code. Please take a look, you can also see a working sample and modify here: https://uqdil.csb.app/

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const getUserData = async (page) => {
    try {
      const url = `https://randomuser.me/api?page=${page}`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      setUserData([...userData, ...response.data.results]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error >> ", error);
    }
  };

  const getUser = (page = 1) => {
    setPage(page);
    getUserData(page);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  const getUserName = (user) => {
    const {
      name: { first, last }
    } = user;
    return `${first} ${last}`;
  };

  const getImagUrl = (user) => {
    const {
      picture: { large }
    } = user;
    return `${large}`;
  };

  if (!userData) {
    return <p>Loading user data ... </p>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {userData.map((user, idx) => {
        const userName = getUserName(user);
        return (
          <div key={idx} style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
            <img alt={userName} src={getImagUrl(user)} />
            <p>User Name: {userName}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          getUser(page + 1);
        }}
      >
        Load More
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It takes you nothing to try it out and see if it works or not with or without it

Comment: I tried it, it works, but is it best practice? I have never seen useState declared without the pair [something, setSomething], so that's why I am asking

Comment: oh okay, it is not a bad practice, what we really do there is called `destructuring`, you should read more about it to understand

Comment: Thanks, once again, the question is unrelated to destructuring. I am just merely trying to understand how to properly use the useState hook in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, if you do not want to change the page.
Now that is not the problem you are having.
as long as that you do not include `page` in your HTML, nothing will re render when you `setPage`
You could also include `var page` on top of `function App` and modify it as you like without trigging an update.

But in this case it will be pointless.

See below how you could modify your code.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const getUserData = async() => {
    try {
      const url = `https://randomuser.me/api?page=${page}`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      setUserData([...userData, ...response.data.results]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error >> ", error);
    }
  };

  const nextPage = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData(); // when page is changed then get users
  }, [page]);

  const getUserName = (user) => {
    const {
      name: {
        first,
        last
      }
    } = user;
    return `${first} ${last}`;
  };

  const getImagUrl = (user) => {
    const {
      picture: {
        large
      }
    } = user;
    return `${large}`;
  };

  if (!userData) {
    return <p > Loading user data... < /p>;
  }
  return ( <
    div className = "App" > {
      userData.map((user, idx) => {
        const userName = getUserName(user);
        return (<div key = {
            idx
          }
          style = {
            {
              marginTop: "20px"
            }
          }>
          <img alt = {
            userName
          }
          src = {
            getImagUrl(user)
          }/> 
          <p> User Name: {
            userName
          } </p> 
          </div>
        );
      })
    } 
    <button onClick={nextPage}>
    Load More 
    </button> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the closest we are going to get. We have to either choose that page variable to not be state and possibly run into mutability problems, or add it to the state and deal with a re-render that does not update the user interface. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, I believe so to. Glad I could help. Do not forget to mark my answer as answer if nothing more come along.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just declare const [page] = useState(1); instead of const [page, setPage] = useState(1); and not call setPage at all?

If you don't want to change the state, then yes, you can just destructure element 0 of the array. That's pretty rare though, since usually the reason for having a state variable is that you want it to be able to change.

About the only reason i can think of to create a state that will never change is that you have some value which is changing beyond your control, and you want to remember what the value was on the first render. Since useState's default value is only used on the first render, useState kinda lets you do that:

```
const Example = ({ propThatMayChange }) => {
  const [initialValue] = useState(propThatMayChange);

  // ...
}
```

The same can also be achieved with a ref, though since it's a mutable object someone might in principle change it:

```
const Example = ({ propThatMayChange }) => {
  const initialValueRef = useRef(propThatMayChange);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can look more into the use of refs and how they can help in this particular situation